# I cannot conect with Web Service from CSV File

Tags: scala, csv, gatling

I have to connect with a web a web service from CSV file, in this file i have usernames and passwords.

I can read the csv file, but i can not connect.

Im doing a stress test,  i need to simulate that several users do a certain action.Im using Gatling, my code:

```
    val csvFeeder = csv("Users.csv").circular // use a comma separator
    val headers_12 = Map(
    "Content-length" -> "1135",
    "Content-type" -> "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "SOAPAction" -> """""""")
    val uri1 = "http://urldestine/b000000001/" 

   print("*******")
   print("*******")
   print(csvFeeder)


    object IC6SaaS {
    val ic = feed(csvFeeder)
        .exec(http("request_12")
        .post("/b0101011010/webserviceexample")
        .headers(headers_12)
        //.body(RawFileBody("SearchAccountNumberxxx_0012_request.txt"))
        .body(StringBody("""{

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-
ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.blabla.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.blabla.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<tns:methodwebservice xmlns:tns="http://webserviceexample.com/">
  <login>${Username}</login>
  <password>${pass}</password>
  <program>1</program>
</tns:methodwebservice>
```

```
    }"""))

        check(regex("""errors""").count.is(0)))




}
```

Someone can help me?

Im new in Gatling, i need to a hand..

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about

```
val httpConf = http
.baseURL("url")
.acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
.acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
.acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
.userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0")
```

and

```
scen = scenario("TEST") exec (IC6SaaS.ic)
```

and

```
 setUp(scen inject atOnceUsers(usersNumber)) protocols httpConf
```